# How to get a creation date from a SPListItem that is a folder in c#?

Tags: development, visual-web-part, folder, metadata

I am making a visual webpart in SP 2010, and I download the SPListItems from a document library. I need to get the creation date of all the documents and folder items. I can do it successfuly for items that are documents and not folders using:

```
DateTime now = System.DateTime.Today;

TimeSpan diff = now - item.File.TimeCreated;
```

But if I try to do this for a item that is a folder, I get an exception about a null object. I think the "File" variable is null value.

Does anyone know how to get the creation date of a folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to get the creation date of folder:

```
item.Folder.Item["Created"]
```

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to `item["Created"]` directly?

Comment: Check the answer by @dylan. Looks like that was throwing exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case, most likely the `File` property of the list item is null, because the list item  refers to a folder and not a file.

I don't see anything similar to `TimeCreated` in the [SPFolder properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder_properties.aspx), so you could get the creation date of a folder by getting the creation date of it's list item, for instance:

```
DateTime created = null;
if (item.File != null)
{
    created = item.File.TimeCreated;
}
else
{
    created = (DateTime)item["Created"];
}
```

Comment: when I try that I get the error

`(8/22/2013 1:49:58 PM) - Error Message: Value does not fall within the expected range.
Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetColumnNumber(String groupName, Boolean bThrowException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)`

Comment: Looks like there is a created timestamp in hashtable of SPFolder.Properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have item initiated as SPListItem.Item[some index]. For a folder you need to change that to SPListItem.Folder.Item["Created"]. Give this code a shot.

```
DateTime created = item.File.TimeCreated;

if (created == null)
{
    created = item.Folder.Item.File.TimeCreated;
}

//rest of your logic
```